# About Webpack asset size limit and same font with different type loading

Tags: css, webpack, fonts

I'm using webpack 5.

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.

I know that I could turn off the hint by

```
performance: {
  hints: false
}
```

And I have two question

I imported same font with ttf,woff,woff2 and have seen this warning because of large ttf size.

1. If there any way to reduce this size in Webpack?? Or just this hint is outdated??
2. Would big asset size by importing same font with different type have a significant impact on performance with real user?